# EnableClientValidation with multiple forms

Tags: validation, asp.net-mvc-2

I am trying to use the Client-side Validation with jQuery in ASP.NET MVC (2).
I've found this great [example](http://geekswithblogs.net/stun/archive/2010/02/27/asp.net-mvc-client-side-validation-summary-with-jquery-validation-plugin.aspx)

which works fine but I am having problems when I try to use a custom name for my form.
It seems that the **EnableClientValidation** methods uses the default form name "form0" to inject the client script and doesn't support any other name. 
Here's a code sample of what I am trying to do:

```
<%=Html.ValidationSummaryJQuery("Please fix these errors.", "id", "BPValidationID")%>
<% Html.EnableClientValidation()%>
<%  Using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "Home", New With {.Id = Model.Code}, FormMethod.Post, New With {.id = "EditForm"}))%>
        <% ViewContext.FormContext.ValidationSummaryId = "BPValidationID"%>
        <%=Html.AntiForgeryToken("AF-BP-SPED-token")%>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Fields</legend>
        <div class="editor-label">
            <%=Html.LabelFor(Function(m) m.Name)%>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            <%=Html.TextBoxFor(Function(m) m.Name)%>
            <%=Html.ValidationMessageFor(Function(m) m.Name, "*")%>
        </div>
        <p>
            <input type="submit" name="submitButton" value="Save" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>            
    <%End Using%>
```

Is there any chance for me to use a FORM name, in case I want to use multiple forms on my page?

Thanks for any help,

Alberto

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've changed the extension method ValidationSummaryJQuery; this method now receives an object instead of a IDictionary.

Answer (score 1):

I presume you mean form `id`? Forms don't have `name`s. Anyway, `EnableClientValidation` works fine with custom form `id`s. If you're having a problem, look at the generated HTML/JS.

This is real-world, working code:

```
<% Html.EnableClientValidation(); %> 
<% using (Html.BeginForm(null, 
                         null, 
                         new RouteValueDictionary{{ "Id", Html.ModelId() }, { "ReturnUrl", ViewData.Eval("ReturnUrl") }}, 
                         FormMethod.Post, 
                         new Dictionary<string, object> { { "id", "editForm" } })) { %>
    <div id="row1">
        <%: Html.EditorForModel() %>
    </div>
```

The rendered form is:

```
<form action="/Snipped/Url" id="editForm" method="post">
    <div id="row1">
        <input ...
```

Comment: Yes, I meant FORM id, sorry for my mistake. As soon as I add the Html.EnableClientValidation() my FORM id becomes form0.

Comment: It shouldn't. Mine doesn't. I'll update the answer with a real-world, working syntax example.

Comment: You're right. It works fine in C#. I don't know what's wrong in Vb.Net but is seems that the problems is there. Thanks for your support Craig.

Comment: I've changed the extension method ValidationSummaryJQuery and everything works fine now. This method now receives an object instead of a IDictionary<string, object>

Comment: Hi Vandalo,

I guess you figured out why it isn't working for you.
Yes as you noticed, my HTML Helper Extension method accepts a Dictionary.


I didn't like using the `object` and converting it to a `Dictionary` using Reflection.
That's why I intentionally was using the `Dictionary`.

Sorry I replied late, but I'm glad you figured it out.
Maybe I'll add in a new extension method that accepts an `object`.

-Soe

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Stun. Yes, I guess using an IDictionary in VB.NET 9 and trying to call it with an object initializer is a bit of a pain.I've changed it with an object so I can call it like this: New With {.id = "BPValidationID"}